# AsyncDisplayKit / Texture: No visible @interface for 'ASDiplayNode' declares the selector 'nodeViewDidAddGestureRecognizer'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode8, asyncdisplaykit

AsyncDisplayKit / Texture is giving me a lot of errors. Using v2.3.2 of Texture in Xcode 8.2.1. It gives me this error right after doing 'pod install' or 'pod update' and opening the workspace.

```
_ASDisplayView.mm:243:26: No visible @interface for 'ASDisplayNode' declares the selector 'nodeViewDidAddGestureRecognizer'

ASDisplayNode.mm:661:3: Use of undeclared identifier 'ASDisplayNodeAssertLockUnownedByCurrentThread'

ASDisplayNode.mm:844:41: No member named 'viewEverHadAGestureRecognizerAttached' in 'ASDisplayNodeFlags'

ASDisplayNode.mm:874:10: No member named 'viewEverHadAGestureRecognizerAttached' in 'ASDisplayNodeFlags'

ASDisplayNode.mm:1006:3: Use of undeclared identifier 'ASDisplayNodeAssertLockUnownedByCurrentThread'

ASDisplayNode.mm:1153:3: Use of undeclared identifier 'ASDisplayNodeAssertLockUnownedByCurrentThread'

ASDisplayNode.mm:1377:3: Use of undeclared identifier 'ASDisplayNodeAssertLockUnownedByCurrentThread'

ASDisplayNode.mm:1407:3: Use of undeclared identifier 'ASDisplayNodeAssertLockUnownedByCurrentThread'

ASDisplayNode.mm:1436:3: Use of undeclared identifier 'ASDisplayNodeAssertLockUnownedByCurrentThread'

ASDisplayNode.mm:1450:28: No visible @interface for 'ASLayout' declares the selector 'frameForElement:'

ASDisplayNode.mm:2094:60: No visible @interface for 'ASRunLoopQueue<ASDisplayNode *>' declares the selector 'initWithRunLoop:retainObjects:handler:'
```

Any idea what could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with similar issue after switching asyncdisplaykit for texture, I've been going through and matching the now undeclared identifiers with functions from the texture pod that had similar names/parameter returns.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Stackoverflow is not a forum, please keep the structure of it. This is more a comment than an answer. When you have enough reputation you can post comment.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the advice. I was looking to debug the issue with Benny G but I don't see any option to directly message or comment with him. :(

Comment: I'm not investigating this anymore, nor did I find a solution. I didn't give up, but Apple kicked my apps out of the app store. Breaking some new guideline. Lots of wasted time and money on my side :(